# Publish SOAP web service in .NET Core 6.0 to IIS

Tags: .net-core, iis, soap, publish

I have seen several tutorials on how to publish a SOAP service made in .NET Core 6.0 in an IIS but I can't get it to work.

This is the configuration:

[image: publish configuration]

From the execution of the project in Visual Studio it opens without problems: `localhost:1234/Service.asmx` but when launching the publication to an IIS of another computer I can't get it to respond to the address: `http://LOCALHOST:1819/Service.asmx`

[image: debug response service in visual studio]

Can someone give me some information to correctly configure publishing to an IIS? Give me some advice or give me some tutorial?

Thank you so much

I have tried several configurations and in no case have I been able to get the service to respond to me.

Comment: So you want to publish to another PC? Have you tested deploying it locally and testing if it works? If your project is .net core application with SOAP service, just refer to the official .net core documentation.

Answer (score 1):

For another person:

This tutorial explained how to create, configure, and deploy a SOAP service using .NET Core 6.0 and the SOAPCore package. The main steps included:

Creating a new .NET Core 6.0 project. (ASP NET CORE Web API)

Installing the SOAPCore NuGet package.

Implementing a SOAP service contract (interface) and the corresponding service implementation.

Configuring the service in the Program.cs file. Example:

```
using SoapCore;
using SOAP_CORE_V1.Service;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddSoapCore();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configura el middleware
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
  app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseRouting(); // Asegúrate de que esta línea esté presente

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
  endpoints.MapControllers();
  app.UseSoapEndpoint<IService>("/SOAP_CORE_V1.asmx", new SoapEncoderOptions());
});

app.Run();
```

Debugging and running the service in a development environment using IIS Express and Visual Studio. EXAMPLE:

```
http://LOCALHOST:12345/SOAP_CORE_V1.asmx
```

Publish the application using dotnet publish or Visual Studio.

[Install the ASP.NET Core module on the IIS server](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet)

Create a new website or application in IIS, pointing to the published output folder.

Configure the web.config file for the production environment.
Set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable to "Production" in the web.config file. EXAMPLE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SOAP_CORE_V1.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" >
        <environmentVariables>
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Production" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

After following these steps, the SOAP service should be running and accessible in : `HTTP://ip:port/SOAP_CORE_V1.asmx`

Comment: Poor quality right now: 1) `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` is missing in your pasted `web.config` example. 2) Badly formatted, and you should spend more time on the Markdown syntax.

Comment: Excuse me, sir, but I believe it's worse not to answer the question by improving what, humbly, I have answered myself in order to, humbly, try to help someone else who might be looking for information. You're welcome.